# PHP For Loop Stopping Too Early Sometimes

Tags: php, for-loop

I'm having a weird issue with a for loop.  I'm passing an array to a function that outputs values based on three array keys (it's actually creating a select box): select_min, select_max, and select_step.  Most of the time, it works.  Sometimes it doesn't increment the final time.  I've tried hard-coding the values that don't work properly, as well.

The code is:

```
for( $a = $property['select_min']; $a <= $property['select_max']; $a += $property['select_step'] ) {
    echo $a . "<br/>";
}
```

I've tested it with a "step" of 0.1 to 1.2.  I can't figure out why it doesn't work in certain instances.  It only seems to be an issue with decimal values.

Min: 0, Max: 20, Step: 1 - This works, outputting 0-20 in increments of 1.

Min: 0.2, Max: 3, Step: 0.2 - This doesn't work, outputting 0.2 to 2.8 in increments of 0.2, but not outputting 3.  Doesn't matter what Max I put, it seems to always fail...except it worked when I ran it from 0 to 22.

Min: 0, Max: 7, Step: 0.7 - This doesn't work.  Doesn't output 7.

Interesting case:

Min: 0, Max: 3, 6, or 9, Step: 0.3 - Works

Min: 0, Max: 12 or 15, Step: 0.3 - Doesn't work

I've done numerous other tests and can't find a common thread behind why it doesn't work in these specific instances.

EDIT:
Thanks for all of the responses.  I ended up using Petah's solution and came up with this:

```
for( $a = $property['select_min']; 
    bccomp( $a , $property['select_max'] , 1 ) <= 0; 
    $a = bcadd( $a , $property['select_step'] , 1 ) ) {
        $str_editor_html .= '<option value="' . ( !is_float( $property['select_step'] ) ? str_replace( ".0" , "" , $a ) : $a ) . '"' . ( strval( $value['setting'] ) == strval( $a ) ? ' SELECTED' : '' ) . '>' . ( !is_float( $property['select_step'] ) ? str_replace( ".0" , "" , $a ) : $a ) . '</option>';
}
```

I added a check for !is_float() on the "step" variable.  If it's an integer, I'm stripping the decimal and trailing zero off for display cleanliness.  There might be a more direct way to do that, but this works perfectly.

Thanks again, y'all!

Comment: could it be a server timeout or something ? can you check in php.ini file? Are you getting any error message in error logs ?

Comment: also you should check to see if you get the same issue if you hard code the values for min/max/step parameters.

Comment: you know that floating point arithmetic in computers doesn't always add up nicely to integers [link](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/the-real-difference-between-integers-and-floatingp.html)

Comment: Almost positive this will be a PHP float [rounding issue](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)

Comment: Use `for (...;bccomp($a, $property['select_max'], 2) <= 0;...`

Comment: @Maximus2012: both of those make zero sense. 1) that loop is very fast 2) how would hardcoding make any difference?

Comment: Yeah, I have a feeling it's going to be a floating point comparison issue.  I wondered if there might be some problem with that but wasn't finding the answer elsewhere.  I'll check all of these out tomorrow.  Appreciate the help!

Comment: If you used my answer can you please accept it (click the tick next to it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said it is because of floating point precission.

You can use bc math to prevent errors with float:

```
for ($a = $property['select_min']; 
        bccomp($a, $property['select_max'], 2) <= 0; 
        $a = bcadd($a, $property['select_step'], 2)) {
    echo $a . "<br/>";
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php

See it in action here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/dBOmGR

Answer (score 3):

See the following http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Basically, in php there's no guarantees when it comes to comparing floats. In the link above, there's a red box with a description of the issue and what can be used instead.

Answer (score 2):

Floats are stored as binary decimal data and are always an approximation of the real number. So it could happen that adding 0.3 multiple times will be something like 15 but that's not 15.
To solve your problem multiply ever number by a factor (10 or 100) to work only with integers.

Answer (score 1):

Floating point numbers are *approximations*. The binary values use base 2, so calculates with a sum out of 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, .... This cannot give a finite exact value of decimal 0.2 or 0.3. Hence there exists a small error and repeated addition of the same value only enlarges that error.

Answer (score 0):

Float values have limited precision, so when you do 2.0 + 0.1 it's not going to be exactly 2.1.

The easiest way to solve this is to use integers, eg: start from 20, increment by 1, and when you need the value, always divide by 10.

Comment: I would not say that is the easiest way, when  things like bc math exist.

Comment: I find the solution based on integers to be more readable, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: @Petah I don't think bcmath is usefull in this case. It's a simple increment, can be done using integer. Why use bcmath for a simple case like this? We are not talking about complex computation on currency or stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting all of your values to floats. It seems like there may a precision problem here.

Alternatively, try using all integer representations of your floats, i.e. multiplied by 10 ( for the example you provided ).